# Python: Writing Multiple HTML tables to separate Excel sheets

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas

I want to export 5 tables from the HTML page to different sheets in Excel.
I wrote a simple code for that. But whenever I execute it. The excel sheet gets updated with only one table (which is the 5th table).

Can you help me modify this so that each table is written into different sheets of excel:

```
import pandas as pd
 
testml = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tokyo_Ghoul_episodes'
 
dfhtml = pd.read_html(testml)
 
for i, df in enumerate(dfhtml):
    
df.to_excel('multitest.xlsx', 'sheet_%s' % i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is a modification to your code;

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

with ExcelWriter('multitest.xlsx') as writer:
for i, df in enumerate(dfhtml):
    df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % i)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @theseeker. This mod works perfectly !!!!!